# CGPath AddLineToPoint not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am trying to draw a diagonal line in my Xamarin.iOS app using the graphics context in my `UIView`:

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);

    using (var gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
    {
        var path = new CGPath();
        path.AddLineToPoint(rect.Width, rect.Size.Height);
        gctx.AddPath(path);
        gctx.SetLineWidth(5);
        gctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);
        gctx.FillPath();
        gctx.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
    }
}
```

I expect to see a red diagonal line, but I don't see anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can achieve that via the code like the below code snippet:

```
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        using (var gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            gctx.SetStrokeColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);
            gctx.SetLineWidth(2.0f);
            gctx.MoveTo(0, 0);
            gctx.AddLineToPoint(rect.Width, rect.Height);
            gctx.StrokePath();
        }

    }
```

It works like this:

[image]